# Store and access value obtained during startup from my controller

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I am using the opened connect middleware to authenticate with a third party oidc provider and everything is up and running as I would expect. During the token exchange I exchange my auth code for an access token which is successful but I then need to store this bearer token for use later in subsequent requests. The token exchange is done as part of my startup class (by overriding the `OpenIdConnectEvents` during the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` method) in the asp.net core project and I need to store and access that token in my controllers.

As there is no “session” per se yet, what is the most effective (or recommended way) to store this token value from the startup class and make it accessible in my controllers?

Ive tried to use IMemoryCache but despite putting the value in the cache during this startup phase, when I try and access that cache in my controller, it is always empty.

Is there a better/preferred way of persisting values form the startup class for later use in the lifecycle?

I can see in `HttpContext.Authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature.Handler.Options` I have access to all the `OpenIdConnectOptions` properties and settings for oidc, but nowhere can I see the actual token value that I stored after the token exchange.

Comment: I believe the openid middleware should setup your ClaimsPrinciple for you which would be accessible through the User object exposed to anything inheriting from Controller base class. I think that might have what you need already.

Comment: @stevejgordon: I have access to the ClaimsPrinciple on HttpContext.User, yes, but this doesn't give me access to the bearer token value in asp.net core - at least as far as I can see from Intellisense. I can access the claims but not the token data itself?

Comment: I can see in HttpContext.Authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature.Handler.Options I have access to all the OpenIdConnectOptions properties and settings for oidc, but nowhere can I see the actual token value that I stored after the token exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. It is available on HttpContext via the AuthenticationManager:

```
var idToken = ((AuthenticateInfo)HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("Cookies").Result).Properties.Items[".Token.id_token"];
```

Works a treat :)

Answer (score 2):

I use a similar approach with Auth0 and JWT.  I store some app_metadata on the claims server, retrieve, and use these values in my controllers for every request.

Startup.cs Configure

```
var options = new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Audience = AppSettings.Auth0ClientID,
            Authority = AppSettings.Auth0Domain
        };

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
        app.UseClaimsTransformation(new ClaimsTransformationOptions
        {
            Transformer = new Auth0ClaimsTransformer()
        });
```

AdminClaimType

```
public abstract class AdminClaimType : Enumeration
{
    public static readonly AdminClaimType AccountId = new AccountIdType();
    public static readonly AdminClaimType ClientId = new ClientIdType();
    public static readonly AdminClaimType IsActive = new IsActiveType();

    private AdminClaimType(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName)
    {

    }

    public abstract string Auth0Key { get; }
    public abstract string DefaultValue { get; }

    private class AccountIdType : AdminClaimType
    {
        public AccountIdType() : base(1, "AccountId")
        {             
        }

        public override string Auth0Key => "accountId";
        public override string DefaultValue => "0";
    }

    private class ClientIdType : AdminClaimType
    {
        public ClientIdType() : base(2, "ClientId")
        {
        }

        public override string Auth0Key => "clientId";
        public override string DefaultValue => "0";
    }

    private class IsActiveType : AdminClaimType
    {
        public IsActiveType() : base(3, "IsActive")
        {
        }

        public override string Auth0Key => "isActive";
        public override string DefaultValue => "false";
    }
}
```

Auth0ClaimsTransformer

```
public class Auth0ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformer
{

    private string _accountId = AdminClaimType.AccountId.DefaultValue;
    private string _clientId = AdminClaimType.ClientId.DefaultValue;
    private string _isActive = AdminClaimType.IsActive.DefaultValue;

    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
    {
        //TODO: Clean up and simplify AdminClaimTypes Transformer
        foreach (var claim in context.Principal.Claims)
        {
            switch (claim.Type)
            {
                case "accountId":
                    _accountId = claim.Value ?? _accountId;
                    break;
                case "clientId":
                    _clientId = claim.Value ?? _clientId;
                    break;
                case "isActive":
                    _isActive = claim.Value ?? _isActive;
                    break;
            }
        }
        ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity)
            .AddClaims(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(AdminClaimType.AccountId.DisplayName, _accountId),
                new Claim(AdminClaimType.ClientId.DisplayName, _clientId), 
                new Claim(AdminClaimType.IsActive.DisplayName, _isActive)
            });

        return Task.FromResult(context.Principal);
    }
```

BaseAdminController

```
//[Authorize]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ApiExceptionFilter))]
[Route("api/admin/[controller]")]
public class BaseAdminController : Controller
{
    private long _accountId;
    private long _clientId;
    private bool _isActive;

    protected long AccountId
    {
        get
        {
            var claim = GetClaim(AdminClaimType.AccountId);
            if (claim == null)
                return 0;

            long.TryParse(claim.Value, out _accountId);
            return _accountId;
        }
    }

    public long ClientId
    {
        get
        {
            var claim = GetClaim(AdminClaimType.ClientId);
            if (claim == null)
                return 0;

            long.TryParse(claim.Value, out _clientId);
            return _clientId;
        }
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            var claim = GetClaim(AdminClaimType.IsActive);
            if (claim == null)
                return false;

            bool.TryParse(claim.Value, out _isActive);
            return _isActive;
        }
    }

    public string Auth0UserId
    {
        get
        {
            var claim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            return claim == null ? string.Empty : claim.Value;
        }
    }

    private Claim GetClaim(AdminClaimType claim)
    {
        return User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == claim.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Now in my controller classes that inherit from BaseAdminController I have access to:

- AccountId
- ClientId
- IsActive
- Auth0UserId
- Anything else I want to add

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @trevorc. I guess my issue is that when I do my Token exchange in startup.cs I get the raw Bearer token value back in a string, which I parse and set on the AuthorisationCodeReceivedContext, but need to access this raw data later from a controller........................

public static async Task AuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext ctx)
        {
   var tk =  DoTokenExchangeHereAndReturnAnOpenIdConnectMessageObject()
            ctx.TokenEndpointResponse = tk;

            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }